# How to join the tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to join two tables, `std_entry_master` and `std_parent_info`. Here is my code to join the tables:

```
SELECT Student_F_Name, Student_M_Name, Student_L_Name, std_entry_master.ID, std_entry_master.Student_ID, Section_ID, Contact_Name
FROM std_entry_master
JOIN std_parent_info on 'STU00000060'=std_parent_info.Student_ID 
WHERE std_entry_master.Student_ID = 'STU00000060';
```

Although it works fine when it finds STU00000060 in `Student_ID` column in `std_parent_info` table, when it doesn't find STU00000060, it gives me the empty result set.

Is there any way to view rest of the column except `Contact_Name` if STU00000060 is not present in the `std_parent_info` table?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is left join.

Comment: Do you have same ids in both tables? What are you JOINing tables on? Sorry not clear

Comment: Show us your table structure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is left join:

```
SELECT Student_F_Name,
       Student_M_Name,
       Student_L_Name,
       std_entry_master.ID,
       std_entry_master.Student_ID,
       Section_ID,
       Contact_Name
FROM   std_entry_master
       LEFT JOIN std_parent_info
         ON std_entry_master.Student_ID = std_parent_info.Student_ID
WHERE  std_entry_master.Student_ID = 'STU00000060';
```

Comment: If you are using the query above, it's because you select by Student_ID.
Try removing the where or change it to `where std_entry_master.Student_ID in ('STU00000060','STU00000061')

Comment: Where can you find the Student_ID 'STU00000061'. Is it in std_entry_master or in std_entry_master

Comment: Student_ID column is in both table And im joining these table on std_entry_master Student_ID and std_parent_info Student_ID.

Comment: If you don't see the result you want to have, you can just try out the other joins, like a `full outer join` or a `right join` may be one of those will give you the result you need.

Answer (score -1):

If you use 'left outer join' instead of a standard 'join' this will return the values you require.